# C# byte array doesn't understand by Java

Tags: java, c#, memcached

i am using memcache , for communicating between java and c#.
c# put data into memcache in byte[] format and  from java application trying to read that byte array but in Java i m getting String Object .
Sample :- C# code

```
MemcachedClient _mc = new MemcachedClient();
_mc.Serverlist = { "127.0.0.1:11211" }
byte[] stestValue = GetBytes("india");
m_c.set("key1",stestValue);

private byte[] GetBytes(string str)
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[str.Length * sizeof(char)];
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    return bytes;
}
```

Java Code :-// to fetch data which we set in memcache having key :- Key1

```
MemcachedClient mcc = new MemcachedClient(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 11211));

Object value = mcc.get("key1");
```

here we get string object in Value rather than `byte[]`.

Comment: Can you try `value.getBytes()`?

Comment: @EugenePodskal. `sizeof(char) == 2`, `Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(char)) == 1`

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Oh, yes. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

yes i have tried to get byte[] from this but this byte array length is different from c# byte array.My requirement is to parse byte array by it's length so requirement is
length of byte[] in c# = length in byte[] in Java